# Php Filter array

Tags: php, sql

I need a simple example of php filter array. This function is new for me so please I can't understand complex program of it. 
I want to store filtered data to the database from a simple form where these conditions can exist.
i.e: 
NAME in capital words.
proper email/Password syntax.
proper address and mobile number (1234-1234567)
registration no: 2012-2015-AUP-1234
if any one mistakes an alert or message is displayed.

Comment: It called data validation, there are many answers available for this ..

Comment: You must validate the data.

Comment: @AliZia brother but how, I mean if you give an example to make an array of above data cuz I really want to learn this.

Comment: @WaleedKhan, add me on skype. My ID is `syed_ali_zia`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_filter` :
The official documentation for PHP is full of very understandable examples for each function. These examples are given by the documentation or the community, and follows each function description.
[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Form validation :
A little code example for the script called by your POST form. Of course a lot of changes to this can be made to display the errors the way you like, and perhaps tune more precise checks on each data.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && !ctype_upper($_POST['name'])) {
    $errors[] = 'name should be uppercase';
}
if (isset($_POST['email']) && !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors[] = 'email is invalid';
}
if (isset($_POST['password']) && strlen($_POST['password']) >= 6 && strlen($_POST['password']) <= 16)) {
    $errors[] = 'password should be between 6 and 16 characters length';
}
if (isset($errors)) {
    // do not validate form
    echo '<ul><li>' . join('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
    // ... include the html code of your form here
}
else {
    // ... call things that must work on validated forms only here
}
```